# How exactly does one marginalize over parameters in an N-dimensional likelihood?

Tags: likelihood, hyperparameter

I see no equations for the following, so I'm not sure exactly what they are talking about:

"For each model, we determine the best fit parameters from
the peak of the N-dimensional likelihood surface. For each parameter in the model we also compute its one dimensional likelihood function by marginalizing over all other parameters."

How do you obtain a one-dimensional likelihood function by marginalizing over all other parameters?

Comment: Is my answer helpful or are you looking for *other ways of marginalization*? Are you expecting an answer on *how to do the integration or summation* technically?

Comment: @gwr This was helpful. I am interested in how one technically does the integrals though, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the state of Information $I$, some observations $\{y_i\}$ and some parameters $\theta_p$ where $p \in \{1,2, \ldots n\}$ then in the **continuous case** you get the marginal likelihoods from the joint likelihood $p(\theta_1,\theta_2, \ldots \theta_n |\{y_i\},I)$ by integration:

\begin{align*}
p(\theta_k|\{y_i\},I) &=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \ldots \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(\theta_1,\theta_2, \ldots \theta_n |\{y_i\},I)\,d\theta_{p_1} \cdots \,d\theta_{p_{n-1}} 
\end{align*}

where $p_j \in \{1,2, \ldots n\}\setminus k$

In the **discrete case** you will have sums instead of integrals as you can see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).

Comment: That gives one way of marginalizing, there are others.

Comment: When integrating directly the likelihood with respect to the Lebesgue measure over the other parameters, you make an arbitrary choice of dominating measure, which means that your definition of a profile likelihood is not invariant by reparameterisation.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you. That is what I call a constructive critique and I have learned something. What I am doing here is what I most often see done for a joint posterior distribution; so is the issue of invariance mainly a concern for priors or likelihoods?

Comment: The lack of invariance is an issue for the marginal likelihood: if you substitute for $\theta_{-k}$ a bijective transform of $\theta_{-k}$ that does not modify $\theta_k$ the resulting marginal as defined above will not be the same function of $\theta_k$. In other words, the Jacobian gets in the way and points out the influence of the dominating measure.

Answer (score 2):

**You should always reference your quotes.**

The only reference on the Internet I found with this quote

> "For each model, we determine the best fit parameters from the peak of
>   the N-dimensional likelihood surface. For each parameter in the model
>   we also compute its one dimensional likelihood function by
>   marginalizing over all other parameters." (p.3)

is an cosmology [arxiv paper](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjAxPrp8K7JAhUC1hoKHZmxBlwQFggnMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2Fastro-ph%2F0302209&usg=AFQjCNEnp9QC89bh_VcLkBSqYbPWIa_ueA&sig2=685QQfmvbaKkTEk5zl7dew&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d2s) on WMAP by Spergel et al. (2003). If you turn the page after this quote, you will find an equation defining the expectation under the "marginal likelihood" as
$$<α_i> = \int d^N α\mathcal{L}(α)α_i\,.$$ This means that the "marginal likelihood" is
$$\int d^{N-1} α_{-i}\mathcal{L}(α)\,.$$

If I quote from the previous sentences of the paper as well

> "For each model studied in the paper, we use a Monte Carlo Markov Chain to explore the likelihood surface. We assume flat priors in our basic parameters, impose positivity constraints on the matter and baryon
>   density (these limits lie at such low likelihood that they are
>   unimportant for the models. We assume a flat prior in τ , the optical
>   depth, but bound τ < 0.3. This prior has little effect on the fits but
>   keeps the Markov Chain out of unphysical regions of parameter space. (p.3)"

this means that the authors take a Bayesian stance with a flat prior in their parametrisation.